# How to exclude items in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I'm trying to display a specific set of references on my laravel page by iterating through an foreach loop and styling odd and even iterations differently with @class loop odd / loop even.

However I as I begin the foreach loop with an @if, only some make it into the loop while some are skipped, which messes up my odd / even (e.g. #1, #2 and #4 make it into the loop which means I have two elements styled with loop even.

How can I skip the ones that don't make it into the loop so I can display the result with alternating styling?

```
@foreach ($references as $reference )
    @if(isset($reference['is_startpage']) 
        && $reference['is_startpage'] != 1 
        && isset($reference['content']['featured']) 
        && $reference['content']['featured'] == 1)

        <div @class([
                    'row py-5' => $loop->odd,
                    'row flex-row-reverse py-5'=> $loop->even,
                    ])></div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: You might want to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child instead. Leave it to CSS instead of doing it programmatically. If you do want to do it programmatically, you'll need an iterator inside of your if check

Comment: the php way would be to filter references beforehand. Change the query or use something like `array_filter`. (best done in the view and not the template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, not every loop iteration prints the `<div>` element, so `$loop->even` and `$loop->odd` variables are not valid in your case for implementing that specific logic. However, there are many ways to achieve what you want. The first way that comes into my mind is using a specific counter for that, i.e.:

```
@php $featuredCount = 0; @endphp
@foreach ($references as $reference)
    @if(
        isset($reference['is_startpage']) 
        && $reference['is_startpage'] != 1 
        && isset($reference['content']['featured']) 
        && $reference['content']['featured'] == 1
    )
        @php $featuredCount++; @endphp
        <div @class([
             'row py-5', // These two are always present, no need to conditionally rewrite them
             'flex-row-reverse' => $featuredCount % 2 == 0, // 'Even' check
        ])></div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: `@php $featuredCount = 0; @endphp` that line is inside foreach, you should place it before, otherwise value will be allways 1

Comment: You're right @Kazz, my bad. Edited :)